# how to open terminal that show output of background running python script

Tags: python, linux, ssh, terminal, nohup

I'm new in linux an have a problem,i want to run an python script that is running in remote linux server with ssh.because i use ssh and want to run after closing ssh connection i use `nohup` command.My problem is that i want open new terminal that show output of running python code in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use screen. I guess it does exactly what you are looking for. You can run the job in the foreground inside your screen session and re-attach to the session whenever you want to (without loosing any output).

See this answer for some more details: https://superuser.com/a/292442